# Bluemix: How to revert from toolchain to old DevOps services

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've tried Bluemix open toolchain and would like to revert to old devops services. How could I accomplish this?

I see "Toolchain" button for my new apps and have no idea how to revert to "Add Git" button.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can "Add Git" in my owned organisation. But in other organisation, there is "add toolchain".

Answer (score 0):

We are not generally planning to support a move back to "**add git**" because the latter is deprecated. The old-style "**add git**" will eventually completely be replaced with open `toolchain`. However, since the product is currently in an experimental phase, we can revert individuals as long as they first delete any existing `toolchain` in your organization. This is important because these `toolchain` will interfere with the old `hub.jazz.net`

In Summary:

1. delete any existing `toolchain` in your organization
2. reply to the e-mail which enabled you indicating that you did the delete and that you want to be reverted